# SQL: How to find the minimum number of entries linked from one table to another

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, count, min

Let's say I have some Table_A:

```
A_id | A_val
1      a
2      b
3      c
```

Some Table_B:

```
B_id | B_val
1      d
2      e
3      g
```

and a linker Table_C:

```
A_id | B_id
1      1
2      1
2      2
3      1
3      2
3      3
```

I'm in need of help trying to find the items in *Table A* that has the fewest items in *Table B* linked to it.  I'm currently a beginner with SQL using PostgreSQL and figured it may have something to do with using a sub-query. I've managed to count the links using:

```
SELECT A_id, COUNT(B_id) as Num_links
  FROM TABLE_C
  GROUP BY A_id;
```

But I've no idea where to go from here.

Comment: Do you want to find a single item, or do you mean there may be multiple items that all have the same (lowest) number of items in Table_C?

Comment: I would need to select all items with the same (lowest) number of items in table C.  I'm sorry I didn't include this with the details.

Comment: Can there be entries in table `A` without *any* link in table `C`? And would those be the "winners", having 0 links? Also, you forgot to supply your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `with` clause to give an alias to your "count" query and treat it like a temp table.  Then select the `a_id` with the `num_links` less-than-or-equal-to the lowest count in `num_links`.

```
WITH link_counts AS (
         SELECT a_id, COUNT(b_id) as num_links
           FROM table_c
       GROUP BY a_id
     )
SELECT a_id
  FROM link_counts
 WHERE num_links <= (SELECT MIN(num_links) FROM link_counts)
```

Note that this could return multiple rows if different `a_id` have same (lowest) number of links (for instance if `a_id` 1 and 4 both only had 1 link each).

Comment: See this [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/ff6b2/6).  It works.  Nice work, matts.

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems work very well.  Also I'd like to thank you guys for introducing me to SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RANK()`.  This will rank your Aid's by the `COUNT(Bid)` -- for those that have the same number, all will be returned with the same rank.

```
SELECT *
FROM A T1
  JOIN (
    SELECT Aid, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(Bid)) rnk
    FROM C 
    GROUP BY Aid
    ) T2 ON T1.Id = T2.Aid
WHERE T2.rnk = 1
```

And here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/2b232/1).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the strategy.  Calculate the maximum number of links.  You can do that by revising your query with an `order by` and `limit`.

Next, calculate the total number of links for each row in `tableC`.  For this, I'm using a window function.  The statement:

```
count(*) over (partition by a_id)
```

Says create a variable that is the count of "a"s in my table.

Then join this together.

```
select distinct c.a_id
from (select c.*,
             count(*) over (partition by a_id) as num_links
      from table_c c
     ) c join
     (select a_id, count(*) as num_links
      from table_c c
      group by a_id
      order by 2 asc
      limit 1
     ) cmax
     on c.num_links = cmax.num_links
```

Comment: The question was to find the item in Table_A with the fewest items linked to Table_B, so you should use `asc` instead of `desc`.  Nice solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option. It uses a subquery in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AId, COUNT(*)
FROM C
GROUP BY AId
HAVING COUNT(*) <= ALL (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                        FROM C 
                        GROUP BY AId)
```

And the related [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/2b232/5). I have no idea how this would compare to the other solutions in terms of performance, but it seems to show clearly what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like others here have a more elegant solution... my SQL Fu is a little rusty but this will work as well.

```
CREATE TABLE Table_C
(
    A_id INT,
    B_id INT
);

INSERT INTO Table_C (A_id, B_id) VALUES (13, 112);
INSERT INTO Table_C (A_id, B_id) VALUES (44, 105);
INSERT INTO Table_C (A_id, B_id) VALUES (66, 68);
INSERT INTO Table_C (A_id, B_id) VALUES (13, 113);
INSERT INTO Table_C (A_id, B_id) VALUES (445, 105);
INSERT INTO Table_C (A_id, B_id) VALUES (660, 68);

CREATE TABLE TempTable
(
    A_id INT,
    Cnt INT
);

INSERT INTO
  TempTable (A_id, Cnt)
SELECT
  t.A_id
  , COUNT(t.A_id) AS Cnt
FROM
  Table_C t
GROUP BY
  t.A_id;

SELECT @minCnt := MIN(Cnt) FROM TempTable;

SELECT
  A_id
FROM
  Table_C
GROUP BY
  A_id
HAVING
  COUNT(A_id) = @minCnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH ct AS (
   SELECT a.a_id
         ,count(c.a_id) AS link_ct
         ,min(count(c.a_id)) OVER () AS min_ct
   FROM   table_a a
   LEFT   JOIN table_c c USING (a_id)
   GROUP  BY 1
   )
SELECT a_id, link_ct
FROM   ct
WHERE  link_ct = min_ct;
```

This is similar to what [@matts posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14738948/939860). It differs in some aspects:

- In the CTE `ct` I count `LEFT JOIN` to `table_c`, this way I don't miss rows from `table_a` with **0 connections** to `table_b` which should win according to the definition in the question.
- Compute `min_ct` in the CTE with a window function (and therefore without additional subquery in the final `WHERE` condition). May or may not be faster, it's cleaner in any case.
- Final `WHERE` condition is good with `=` instead of `<=`.

[**->sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6ba15/4) demonstrating the difference.